# PHP process can keep running a casual 16 hour past it's max execution time

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

We are running into an issue that we can't figure out how to fix it... we thought it was fixed a couple times that happened before but it is happening again... and this issue is shutting down the website and we can't really figure out what is causing it.

This is the scenario:

- WordPress website
- Theme: Avada
- PHP Custom code to import vehicles every 3 hours from a CSV file for the website vehicle search

I've tried to change the code that works most of the time but I can't really figure out if my code is the bad guy since we are not getting enough information. Below we have some logs about this issue, any idea or direction we can take to solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtxe2.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvFg9.png)

This is the code:

```
function fn_import_csv(){
    define('EXECUTION', uniqid());
    echo "Execution ".EXECUTION."<br><br>";
    update_option('inventory_update', current_time('m/d/Y h:i A')); //update settings field
    
    $file = fopen(ABSPATH."inventory/MP7220_website.csv", "r");
    fgetcsv($file); //skip first row
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE){
            //check if INSERT or UPDATE
            $rsCheck = array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'inventory', 'post_status' => 'any', 'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'AND', array('key' => 'stock','value' => $data[1], 'compare' => '=')));
            $arCheck = get_posts($rsCheck);

            $title = $data[4]." ".$data[5]." ".$data[6]." ".$data[10]." ".$data[16];
            
            if(count($arCheck) == 0){ //insert inventory
                echo "<b style='color:#2271b1'>INSERT</b> <i>".$data[1]."</i> - ".$title."<br>";
                $id = wp_insert_post(array('post_title' => $title, 'post_type'=> 'inventory', 'post_status' => 'publish'));
                $photosPieces = explode(";", $data[28]);

                $photos = "";
                for($i = 0; $i < count($photosPieces); $i++){
                    $photos .= "<img src='".$photosPieces[$i]."' style='height:100px!important'>";
                }
                add_post_meta($id, 'photos', $photos);
                add_post_meta($id, 'photos_urls', $data[28]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'has_photos', (count($photosPieces) == "1") ? "N" : "Y");
                add_post_meta($id, 'stock', $data[1]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'price', $data[19]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'vin', $data[2]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'newused', $data[3]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'year', $data[4]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'make', $data[5]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'model', $data[6]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'model_code', $data[7]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'body', $data[8]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'transmission', $data[9]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'series', $data[10]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'series_detail', $data[11]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'door_count', $data[12]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'odometer', $data[13]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'engine_cylinder_ct', $data[14]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'engine_displacement', $data[15]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'drivetrain_desc', $data[16]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'color', $data[17]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'interior_color', $data[18]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'description', $data[23]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'features', $data[24]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'city_mpg', $data[25]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'highway_mpg', $data[26]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'engine', $data[31]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'fuel', $data[32]);
                add_post_meta($id, 'execution', EXECUTION);
                add_post_meta($id, 'lock_price_field', "No");
                add_post_meta($id, 'pre_owned', "No");
                add_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $title." ".$data[17]." for sale. Visit Major World in Long Island City #NY serving Queens, Brooklyn and Bronx #".$data[2]);
            }else{ //update inventory
                $ar = json_decode(json_encode($arCheck), true);
                echo "<b style='color:#4fb347'>UPDATE</b> <i>".$ar[0]["ID"]." - ".$data[1]."</i> - ".$title."<br>";
                $id = $ar[0]["ID"];
                $photosPieces = explode(";", $data[28]);

                $photos = "";
                for($i = 0; $i < count($photosPieces); $i++){
                    $photos .= "<img src='".$photosPieces[$i]."' style='height:100px!important'>";
                }
                wp_update_post(array('ID' => $id, 'post_title' => $title));
                update_post_meta($id, 'photos', $photos);
                update_post_meta($id, 'photos_urls', $data[28]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'has_photos', (count($photosPieces) == "1") ? "N" : "Y");
                update_post_meta($id, 'stock', $data[1]);

                if(get_field("lock_price_field", $id) == "No" || get_field("lock_price_field", $id) == ""){ //only update the price if it is not locked
                    update_post_meta($id, 'price', $data[19]);
                }

                update_post_meta($id, 'vin', $data[2]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'newused', $data[3]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'year', $data[4]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'make', $data[5]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'model', $data[6]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'model_code', $data[7]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'body', $data[8]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'transmission', $data[9]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'series', $data[10]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'series_detail', $data[11]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'door_count', $data[12]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'odometer', $data[13]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'engine_cylinder_ct', $data[14]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'engine_displacement', $data[15]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'drivetrain_desc', $data[16]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'color', $data[17]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'interior_color', $data[18]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'description', $data[23]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'features', $data[24]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'city_mpg', $data[25]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'highway_mpg', $data[26]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'engine', $data[31]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'fuel', $data[32]);
                update_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $title." ".$data[17]." for sale. Visit Major World in Long Island City #NY serving Queens, Brooklyn and Bronx #".$data[2]);
                update_post_meta($id, 'execution', EXECUTION);
            }
    }//end while
    fclose($file);

    //remove vehicles
    $argsD = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'inventory',
            'post_status'     => 'any',
            'suppress_filters' => false,
            'meta_query'    => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'execution',
                    'value'     => EXECUTION,
                    'compare'   => '!='
                )
            ),
    ); 
    $postsDelete = get_posts($argsD);
    echo "<br><br><h4>TO BE DELETED - <i>".EXECUTION."</i></h4>"; //(".count($postsDelete).")
    foreach ($postsDelete as $arD){
        echo "- ".$arD->post_title." ".$arD->ID."<br>";
        wp_delete_post($arD->ID);
    }
    //end remove vehicles
    wp_die(); //necessary to prevent 0 from being printed
    exit();
}//end import CSV
```

We've increased all PHP resources to prevent it but at some point they are not enough and it shuts down the website because the process never end.

Comment: How many rows does the CSV have? Also note that PHP often uses own confugration for CLI which by default has no max_execution_time.
Also note that $row variable and related conditions are redundant in your code.
If you want to exclude header from your while loop just call `fgetcsv` once before executing it.
Have you tried logging the import progress somewhere and check if its still running?
Are you using WP_Cron or cron?

Comment: Hi, tks for getting into this. CSV rows vary but now it has 960 rows. I've adjusted my code removing that redundant condition. Tkssss

Comment: How many or these are you running concurrently?